# CSS background-color not applied to all cells with class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, background-color

I've got a table that has a background colour applied every other row for easy view using the `:nth-child` pseudo-class, but uses an additional class to highlight certain information by applying a different background colour to that cell.

The confusing part is that for even rows (where the original style is `background-color: none;`) the highlight colour is applied, but odd rows (where the style is `background-color: #C4A66F;`) don't apply the new highlighted style.

**Image**

[image: Image of problem]

As you can see, the highlighting is sporadic. It should be applied to the 'Inns' column cells when the value is equal to or more than 15. The class (`tqual`) appears in the html as expected.

**HTML**

The html below is within a loop over each row, so the `tqual` class is added correctly to cells with where the value is >= 15.

```
<tr class="tdata">
     <td class="col-name"><?php echo $name; ?></td>
     <td class="col-apps"><?php echo $apps; ?></td>
     <td class="<?php if($inns>=15) echo "tqual ";?>col-inns"><?php echo $inns; ?></td>
     [...]
</tr>
```

**CSS**

```
tr.tdata:nth-child(even) td {
    background-color: none;
}

tr.tdata:nth-child(odd) td {
    background-color: #C4A66F;
}

td.tqual {
    background-color: #DDDD00;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Go read up on _selector specificity_.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is it's overwriting one pseudo class but not the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your TD in the `even` TR *do not have* any `background-color` set – since `none` is not a valid value for that property, so that invalid declaration simply gets *ignored*. (If you want to *override* the background color on an element that already has one from another rule, then you have to use the default value `transparent` to get “no background color”.)

Therefore, the rule with the selector `td.tqual` is able to set a background color for those TD – but not for those in the `odd` TR, because `td.tqual` is a selector with lower specificity than `tr.tdata:nth-child(odd) td`.

(Change `background-color` in your first rule to a *valid* value, f.e. `red` – and you will see that *none* of your TD with class `tqual` will get the yellow background applied any more.)

So the solution is simple: Use a rule with at least the same specificity to give a background color to those `.tqual` cells. (And fix the wrong `background-color` value `none`.)

Comment: Ah I see. `tr.tdata td.tqual` fixes things. Out of interest, I was replacing a normal class based system for the rows that used `background: none;`. Would I be right in saying I'm effectively setting the `background-image` to `none`, and the default for `background-color` was applied (which I assume is `transparent`).